# Pattern finding in an array of numbers

Tags: algorithms, continuations

I have an array of numbers, and I need to check if there is a repeating pattern in the array.
Like, for example, if I have an array A=[1,1,6,1,1,6,1,1,6,1,1,6...] this should return "Yes" (pattern present), 3 (for length of the pattern) or "1,1,6" (the pattern).

In contrast, if I have this array A=[1,1,6,1,1,6,1,2,3..], this should return "No" (because no pattern is found) or 0 (for length of longest pattern).

Does there exist an algorithm for it, that works preferably in O(nlog(n)) or O(n) time?

PS: I would like to decrible the original problem in case there is a method to solve it that hasn't occured to me yet. The original problem asks to find the length of the continued fraction sequence of an irrational number.
For example, for
$\sqrt{2} =[1;(2)]$

Comment: Please give a general specification of the problem.  What exactly is a "repeating pattern"?  An example is not a substitute for a general specification of what the output should be on all possible inputs.  What do the ".." mean?  Normally an array has only finite length.

Comment: @D.W. The "..." means that there are more elements.

Comment: Anyway you need definition of "repeating pattern". Answer is given for iterating sequences - is your array such?

Comment: @zkutch I don't understand what you mean by iterating sequences. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Look on link in answer given by D.W. - it's on first line.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  I know what the ".." notation normally means, but what you have written doesn't make sense; arrays have finite length, so it's not an array if it has infinite length.  Let me put it another way.  How is the array provided as input?  You can't have an infinite-length input.  Please define what exactly you mean by "repeating pattern". For instance, a sequence that begins [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,..] would appear to have a repeating pattern, but suppose that if we were to look out one billion digits we discovered that there's a 7 in the billionth position.  Now what?

Comment: Please don't reply in the comments -- instead, [edit] the question to make the problem statement clearer and more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement is unclear, but under reasonable assumptions:

No.  You can't.  If the input is an infinite sequence, you can't solve it in any finite time.  To put it another way, suppose you have an algorithm that terminates after some fixed amount of time.  Now consider feeding in the input [5,5,5,5,..] to the algorithm.  Presumably, you want it to output that the input repeats "Yes, a pattern of length 1 exists".  Now consider the same input, except that the billionth digit has been changed to a 7.  Now, presumably you want the algorithm to output "No".  Yet an algorithm that takes fewer than one billion steps of computation cannot tell the difference between those two inputs, so such an algorithm will produce the wrong output on at least one of these two inputs.  You can make a similar argument that any finite algorithm will do the wrong thing on some input.

---

Alternatively: if we accept a different definition of what we mean by a "pattern", the problem is solvable efficiently.  Suppose that what we mean is that we have an infinite stream of numbers and we can look as far as we like into it; and if there is any repeating sequence of period longer than one that occurs two or more times, then we are permitted to exit and output "Yes" with that sequence.

In this case, there is an efficient algorithm.  [Floyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) runs in $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ space, and can be adapted to this problem.
Floyd's algorithm will output a bunch of candidates for possible patterns (a candidate for the start of the repeating pattern and its length), and then you need an efficient way to check them.  Fortunately, that check can be done efficiently with a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash).

Unfortunately this problem statement is not consistent with your examples, as under this problem statement, when running the algorithm on any infinite stream that begins with [1,1,6,1,1,6,...], the algorithm is allowed to output "Yes".

---

Finally, I will answer your actual problem about continued fractions, which is a different problem.  The answer to that question is yes, given $n$, you can find whether there exists a continued fraction expansion for $\sqrt{n}$ that is periodic, and find the period.  Using standard algorithms for continued fractions, you can compute the numbers in the continued fraction, one at a time, so we obtain a way to iterate through the infinite stream.  Now the above algorithm gives us candidates for the pattern.

All that we need is a way to verify a candidate pattern.  Suppose we hypothesize that $\sqrt{n} = [a_0;a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{k-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots]$, i.e., we hypothesize the continued fraction has $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}$ repeating infinitely.  This amounts to a hypothesis that

$$\sqrt{n} = a_0 + {1 \over a_1 + {1 \over \ddots + \sqrt{n}}}.$$

We can efficiently check this hypothesis.  Note that the right-hand expression can be simplified to something of the form ${b \sqrt{n} + c \over d \sqrt{n} + e}$ by straightforward arithmetic, e.g.,

$$a_{k-1} + {1 \over \sqrt{n}} = {a_{k-1} \sqrt{n} + 1 \over \sqrt{n}},$$
$$a_{k-2} + {1 \over a_{k-1} + {1 \over \sqrt{n}}} = {(a_{k-1} a_{k-2}+1) \sqrt{n} + a_{k-2}  \over  a_{k-1} \sqrt{n} + 1},$$

etc.  Finally, we can check the hypothesis that

$$\sqrt{n} = {b \sqrt{n} + c \over d \sqrt{n} + e}$$

by cross-multiplication, i.e., we check that

$$dn + e \sqrt{n} = b \sqrt{n} + c,$$

i.e., that $dn=c$ and $e=b$.  Of course, it is known that the solutions of quadratic solutions all have [periodic continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction), and vice versa, so this completely characterizes the situation.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer! Especially the part about continued fractions. Regarding the pattern-in-an-array problem though, I posed that because my initial idea was to find the continued fraction expansion for the irrational upto 1000 terms, and check if there was a pattern in the array. But you have provided a better method, and thank you again!